# If $a=bc$ then $\langle b \rangle / \langle a \rangle \simeq D/\langle c \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces, principal-ideal-domains

$D$ is a PID and $a=bc$, a random factorization of some $0\neq a \in D$. I want to prove $\langle b \rangle / \langle a \rangle \simeq D/\langle c \rangle$

The condition $a=bc$ suggest $1/c=b/a$. Maybe define $\phi: \langle b \rangle \to D/\langle c \rangle , \phi(x)= xc-bc$ which is a morphism in which case $\ker \phi = \langle a \rangle$ and $\frac{\langle b \rangle}{\langle \ker \phi \rangle}\simeq \frac{D}{\langle c \rangle}$.

Comment: $D/(c)$ is a commutative ring with identity. How you are hoping to get the isomorphism?

Comment: Is there a theorem that suggest an isomorphism for commutative rings with identity? I don't see what that fact proves or disproves

Comment: If $D/(c) \simeq (b)/(a)$, then $(b)/(a)$ is also a commutative ring *with identity*. What is the identity element of $(b)/(a)$?

Comment: @Krish Do you mean the additive identity? Then $0+\langle b \rangle$

Comment: No. When I say "ring with identity", that means *"multiplicative identity"*. (This is a commonly used terminology.)

Comment: @Krish $1+ \langle b \rangle$ then.

Comment: $0+(b), 1+(b)$ are **not** even elements of $(b)/(a)$. You are making mistake with the notations. (It's better, at this point, to go back and check the definition and notation regarding quotient ring)

Comment: For the quotient ring $R/I$ its elements should be $[a]$ where $a\in R$ and $[a]=[b]$ if $a-b\in I$. In this case seems that any $a$ will behave as $[0]$ since $[0]=[a]$ because $0-a\in \langle a \rangle$.